# How to integrate `slimscroll` to `Bootstrap` modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slimscroll

I am using Bootsrap modal, in which i am trying to integrate the `slimscroll` plug-in. but it's not working.

here is my code :

```
$("#refinequery").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

                var form = $(this).find('form');

                that.locationDetails(form, that.formInfo.disciplineProperties);
                that.queryDetails(form, that.bodyDetails );

                $('.modal-dialog').css({
                    height : $( window ).height()*1,
                    "overflow-y":'auto'
                });

            }).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).slimscroll({}); //not working properly all are collapsed!
            }).modal();
```

Comment: I've tried playing around with slimscroll a bit, see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/QwdZqQ?editors=101. It only works the first time you press _Open_. It seems that slimscroll can only be applied to an element once, which would become a problem if you want the height to be changed when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy any existing relationship your modal has to slimScroll prior to initializing it. The following works with your CodePen example.

```
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myModal .modal-body')
    .slimscroll({ destroy: true })
    .slimscroll({ height: '500px' })
    .text(text);
});
```